# Конструкция return this

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет. Возник вопрос, что означает `return this;`, который обычно встречается в методах? В пользовательском конструкторе `this` используется когда, поля класса и аргументы конструктора имеют одинаковое имя, как здесь:

```
public IntValue(int value)
{
   this.value = value;
}
```

А что означает `return this;`, не очень понятно? Я думаю эту запись ввели для сокращения кода, и возможно обойтись как-то без `return this;`, если такое возможно покажите? 
Если я правильно понял, то код, который я привёл ниже в реализация интерфейса - IEnumerable возвращает экземпляр класса `UserCollection` приведенный к базовому интерфейсному типу и `this` в данном случае это и есть ссылка на экземпляр класса `UserCollection`?

```
namespace InterIEnumerable
{
    // Класс UserCollection коллекция (набор) объектов класса Element.
    // Для применения foreach, необходимо, чтобы класс реализовывал интерфейс - IEnumerable.
    public class UserCollection : IEnumerable, IEnumerator
    {
        public Element[] elementsArray = null;

        public UserCollection()
        {
            elementsArray = new Element[4];
            elementsArray[0] = new Element("A", 1, 10);
            elementsArray[1] = new Element("B", 2, 20);
            elementsArray[2] = new Element("C", 3, 30);
            elementsArray[3] = new Element("D", 4, 40);
        }

        // Указатель текущей позиции элемента в массиве.
        int position = -1;

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Реализация интерфейса IEnumerator.

        // Передвинуть внутренний указатель (position) на одну позицию.
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (position < elementsArray.Length - 1)
            {
                position++;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Установить указатель (position) перед началом набора.
        public void Reset()
        {
            position = -1;
        }

        // Получить текущий элемент набора. 
        public object Current
        {
            get { return elementsArray[position]; }
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Реализация интерфейса - IEnumerable.

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this as IEnumerator;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, реализация `IEnumerable` ужасна. Она не позволяет двум участникам одновременно независимо перечислять коллекцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ээхм.

`this.value` — это не магическая конструкция, означающая «не тот `value`, а другой, который я имею в виду».

`this` — это ссылка на вполне конкретный объект, и `this.value` — это совершенно обыкновенное обращение к полю этого объекта. Этот вызов ничем не отличается от вызова `obj.value` по другой ссылке (если, конечно, тип ссылки `obj` такой же).

Внутри нестатических методов объекта `this` является ссылкой на этот объект. Вне нестатических методов пользоваться `this` нельзя. Соответственно, если вы возвращаете ссылку на `this`, вы возвращаете ссылку на объект, в тором выполняется тот самый метод, откуда вы пытаетесь вернуть значение.

Никакой мистики.

Comment: Допустим есть некий класс `UserCollection` и если метод в данном классе возвращает `return this`, то следовательно он возвращает ссылку самого себя, на свой экземпляр класса?

Comment: @ВасилийТерентьев: `this` есть ссылка на тот экземпляр класса, в котором бежит метод. Соответственно, если метод эту ссылку возвращает, то он возвращает ссылку на тот экземпляр класса, в котором бежит этот метод.

Comment: То есть если метод объявлен в классе `UserCollection` то он возвращает ссылку на экземпляр класса  `UserCollection` ? Или он возвращает экземпляр класса где данный метод вызывается, допустим тот же `Program`? Просто я не понял, что значит "бежит метод", это его вызов или инициализация, или что-то другое?

Comment: *Единственное отличие — при доступе к полям/методам через this вы можете обращаться к private- и protected-членам.* А разве по любой другой ссылке такого же статического типа Вы не можете обращаться к `private` и `protected` членам?

Comment: @PetSerAl: Точно, с [прямым углом спутал](https://ideone.com/UOZkl7).

Comment: @ВасилийТерентьев: Ну, у вас есть статические и нестатические классы — верно? Статические методы вызываются по имени типа. А нестатические вызываются _у какого-то экземпляра_. Вот этот-то экземпляр и доступен по ссылке `this`.

Answer (score 5):

Просто чтобы можно было делать не так:

```
var x = new Smth();
x.DoSmth1();
x.DoSmth2();
x.DoSmth3();
x.DoSmth4();
var res = x.Value;
```

а вот так (точнее, чтобы сделать эти записи эквивалентными):

```
var x = new Smth();
var res = x.DoSmth1().DoSmth2().DoSmth3().DoSmth4().Value;
```

потому что это может быть удобнее и позволять исключить лишнюю переменную.

Это называется чейнингом (chaining) от слова "chain" - "цепь".

> кста, а в таких конструкциях есть оверхеад на возвращение обьекта или большее использование стека?

Cтек используется так же, как раньше - ничего не меняется, поскольку вызовы последовательные, а не вложенные. Ну, потенциально может быть разница в 8 байт по сравнению с void, но я почти уверен, что возврат будет идти через регистр, а не через стек; да и 8 байт ни на что не влияют, поскольку они не зависят от числа вызовов.

Сама по себе операция возврата тоже довольно дешёвая, плюс, она может хорошо сочетаться со следующим вызовом в цепочке (`mov` переместится из кода вызова в код функции) и получится один лишний возврат на всю цепочку.

В общем, я считаю, что никакого оверхэда нет. А если и есть, то ни на что не повлияет - любая операция в коде будет больше, чем этот оверхэд.

https://ideone.com/989mWC - все результаты в пределах погрешности

```css
html, body, #cs, pre {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

pre, #cs {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}

pre {
  width: 14ch;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<pre>Успешно #stdin #stdout 0.03s 15972KB
360000 3350
360000 2595
360000 422
360000 287

Успешно #stdin #stdout 0.01s 131648KB
360000 2241
360000 2387
360000 234
360000 308

Успешно #stdin #stdout 0.01s 131776KB
360000 2184
360000 1382
360000 181
360000 238

Успешно #stdin #stdout 0.01s 131712KB
360000 1731
360000 1381
360000 179
360000 237</pre>

<script type="text/plain" id="cs">using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
 
class Smth
{
  public int Sum;
  public void Add1(int x) { Sum += x; }
  public Smth Add2(int x) { Sum += x; return this; }
}
 
public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var x = new Smth();
    const int MAXN = 10000;
 
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
 
    x.Sum = 0;
    sw.Start();
 
    for (var q=0; q<MAXN; ++q)
    {
      x.Add1(1);
      x.Add1(2);
      x.Add1(3);
      x.Add1(4);
      x.Add1(5);
      x.Add1(6);
      x.Add1(7);
      x.Add1(8);
    }
 
    sw.Stop();
 
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x.Sum, sw.ElapsedTicks);
 
    x.Sum = 0;
    sw.Restart();
 
    for (var q=0; q<MAXN; ++q)
    {
      x.Add2(1).Add2(2).Add2(3).Add2(4).Add2(5).Add2(6).Add2(7).Add2(8);
    }
 
    sw.Stop();
 
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x.Sum, sw.ElapsedTicks);
 
    x.Sum = 0;
    sw.Restart();
 
    for (var q=0; q<MAXN; ++q)
    {
      x.Add1(36);
    }
 
    sw.Stop();
 
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x.Sum, sw.ElapsedTicks);
 
    x.Sum = 0;
    sw.Restart();
 
    for (var q=0; q<MAXN; ++q)
    {
      x.Add2(36);
    }
 
    sw.Stop();
 
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", x.Sum, sw.ElapsedTicks);
  }
}</script>
```

Comment: кста, а в таких конструкциях есть оверхеад на возвращение обьекта или большее использование стека?

Comment: @user184868, стек используется так же, как раньше - ничего не меняется, поскольку вызовы последовательные, а не вложенные (ну, потенциально может быть разница в 8 байт по сравнению с void, но я почти уверен, что возврат будет идти через регистр, а не через стек; да и 8 байт ни на что не влияют, поскольку они не зависят от числа вызовов). Сама по себе операция возврата тоже довольно дешёвая, плюс, она может хорошо со следующим вызовом в цепочке. В общем, я считаю, что никакого оверхэда нет. А если и есть, то ни на что не повлияет - любая операция в коде будет будьше, чем этот оверхэд.

Comment: копеечные то да для бизнес логики другое дело в цикле на сотни миллионов вызовов. Ради интереса, я попробовал в с# сделать большой цикл, в нём считается например сумма, и то же самое с выделением операции внутри в отдельный метод, так вот второе по времени работает несколько медленнее, а если вынести это в Func  то вообще замедление жуткое.

Comment: @user184868, погоди, какое вынесение в метод? Я говорил о 2 вариантах: метод, который ничего не возвращает (`void`) и метод, который возвращает `this` - между ними разницы не должно быть, либо она должна быть несущественной. Ну и не забудь, что запускать надо в релизе, а не дебаге.

Comment: @user184868, дополнил ответ примером кода.

Comment: действительно сам попробовал разница небольшая, второй стабильно больше но в сотые доли времени. А вот если ты в цикле сделаешь просто  x.Sum++ будет раз в 10 быстрее

Comment: @user184868, ну так вызов функции. Хотя оптимизатор мог бы и заинтайнить...

Answer (score 2):

это ссылка на экхемпляр класса

```
public Object getThis()
{
   return this;
}
Object me = new Object();
Object  result  = me.getThis() ;теперь result == me
```

Comment: То есть по другому можно записать так: `public Object getThis()
{ return me;}`  ?

Answer (score 0):

К другим ответам добавлю что

```
public class MyClass 
{
    int value;

    public SetValue(int value)
    {
        this.value /*(1)*/ = value /*(2)*/;
    }
}
```

(1) это value самого объекта.
(2) это value из аргумента функции

Это удобно, что бы не плодить новых названий аргументов. И реально было задавать например `value` не через `int newValue`, что рождает путаницу а с аргументом с аналогичным именем.